# Power series solutions of the Chebyshev differential equation.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Please someone tell me where to find the full work-out solutions of the following differential equation in terms of power series:
$$(1-x^2)y''-xy'+y=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Try an ansatz of the form,
$$ y(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_k x^k.$$
If you plug this into the differential equation, and compare the coefficients of $x^k$, you should get a recurrence relation for $a_k$. I believe it looks like:
$$ (k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2} - k(k-1)a_k - ka_k + a_k = 0.$$
but I encourage you to check this for accuracy, and then simplify it.

You should now be able to obtain two linearly independent solutions to the recurrence relation, by taking either $a_0 = 1, a_1 = 0$ or $a_0 = 0, a_1 = 1$.

(Note that one of these series solutions terminates, but the other one doesn't!)

Comment: Do you know where can I find the whole work-out solution?

Comment: Sure, socrates.  Take the suggestion, and apply some effort, along with help from your notes, and your text, and apply a bit more effort, and, you can author your own "work-out" solution!